# Can I shift to SAP Testing

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, sap

Currently I am working on manual and automation testing(selenium) and
I am interested in SAP testing.

If I learn SAP testing, will it be useful after learning SAP testing. If I attend interviews with my previous experience, will they hire?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need anyone's permission to shift to SAP testing, but in case you feel you needed one, you have my permission :-)

Regarding if someone will hire you, it depends on your skills and their need, no one here can answer that.